# Brand Names: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm doing an exercise to scrape products off of Sephora using python but after successfully scraping 12 products, I get the the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'".

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the fact that the products are organized into blocks of 12 but I'm having trouble understanding how to fix this.

Code & reference website below. Thank you so so so much!

**My code snippet:**

```
product = soup.find(class_ = "css-zwibo9 e65zztl0")
product_list = product.find_all(class_ = "css-12egk0t")
for product in product_list:
brand_name = product.find(class_= 'css-182j26q').text
```

**Website:**
https://www.sephora.com/shop/sunscreen-sun-protection?pageSize=300

Comment: What tag does class `css-zwibo9` and `e65zztl0` belong to?

Comment: if you get `None` then you should use `try/except` to catch it or use `if variable is not None: variable...`.

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to add elements but `requests/urllib/beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real browser which can run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The data are embedded within the page in Json format. You can use this example how to parse it:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.sephora.com/shop/sunscreen-sun-protection?pageSize=300"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#linkSPA").contents[0])

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data:
for p in data["NthCategory"]["props"]["products"]:
    print(
        "{:<30} {:<80} {}".format(
            p["brandName"],
            p["displayName"],
            p["currentSku"].get("listPrice", "-"),
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Supergoop!                     Unseen Sunscreen SPF 40 PA+++                                                    $20.00 - $44.00
ILIA                           Super Serum Skin Tint SPF 40 Foundation                                          $48.00
Supergoop!                     Glowscreen Sunscreen SPF 40 PA+++                                                $36.00
IT Cosmetics                   CC+ Cream with SPF 50+                                                           $16.00 - $39.50
Dr. Jart+                      Cicapair™ Tiger Grass Color Correcting Treatment SPF 30                          $19.00 - $52.00
NARS                           Pure Radiant Tinted Moisturizer Broad Spectrum SPF 30                            $45.00
Shiseido                       Urban Environment Oil-Free UV Protector Broad Spectrum Face Sunscreen SPF 42     $35.00 - $48.00
Supergoop!                     PLAY Everyday Lotion SPF 50 PA++++                                               $22.00 - $58.00
Laura Mercier                  Tinted Moisturizer Natural Skin Perfector Broad Spectrum SPF 30                  $25.00 - $47.00
Tatcha                         Silken Pore Perfecting Sunscreen Broad Spectrum SPF 35 PA+++                     $65.00

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrej gave a working solution which returns more information. To align with your use of class-searches, the below snippet should work:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get bs4.BeautifulSoup object
url = 'https://www.sephora.com/shop/sunscreen-sun-protection?pageSize=300'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

# Find sunscreen(?) products
product = soup.find("div", {"class": "css-zwibo9"})
product_list = product.find_all("span", {"class": "css-182j26q"})
for product in product_list:
    print(product.text)
```

prints:

```
Supergoop!
ILIA
Supergoop!
IT Cosmetics
Dr. Jart+
NARS
Shiseido
Supergoop!
Laura Mercier
Tatcha
Lancôme
Laura Mercier
```